# C# Best Buy Web Scraping - Can't get add to cart element

Tags: c#, web-scraping, xpath, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I'm writing a simple web scraping application to retrieve information on certain PC components.

I'm using Best Buy as my test website and I'm using the HTMLAgilityPack as my scraper.

I'm able to retrieve the title and the price; however, I can't seem to get the availability.

So, I'm trying to read the Add to Cart button element's text. If it's available, it'll read "Add to Cart", otherwise, it'll read "Unavailable".

But, when I get the XPath and try to save it to a variable, it returns null. Can someone please help me out?

Here's my code.

```
var url = "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/pny-nvidia-geforce-gt-710-verto-2gb-ddr3-pci-express-2-0-graphics-card-black/5092306.p?skuId=5092306";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument pageDocument = web.Load(url);

string titleXPath = "/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/h1";
string priceXPath = "/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span[1]";
string availabilityXPath = "/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[7]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/button";

var title = pageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(titleXPath);
var price = pageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(priceXPath);
bool availability = pageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(availabilityXPath) != null ? true : false;

Console.WriteLine(title.InnerText);
Console.WriteLine(price.InnerText);
Console.WriteLine(availability);
```

It correctly outputs the title and price, but availability is always null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `string availabilityXPath = "//button[. =  'Add to Cart']"`

In web scraping, while a long generated xpath will always work on the same static page, when you're dealing with multiple pages across the same store, the location of certain elements can drift and break your xpaths. Yours is breaking at `/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[7]/div[1]/div` and I suspect that's what's happening here.

Learning to write one from scratch will be invaluable (and much easier to debug!).

Comment: maybe even
//button[contains(@class, 'add-to-cart-button')]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that and it seems to work, I'll have to look up the syntax, but I assume it has something to do with looking for text that matches that. I see what you mean about not being consistent with multiple pages, but, why does the XPath not work for this one page? In theory, it should, right?

Comment: It would seem to me if the product was not unavailable the button wouldn't need to exist (can't click it to add to cart, there's none available), so the 'Unavailable' text would go in the parent element, where the button would be if it was available. Basically, it's possible you need to look for two elements, one when it's available (e.g. the button) and one when the product is not available (e.g. the div). If the `button` element isn't found, either you use the lack of the button to say it's not available, or if  you want to explicitly know, you fall back and look for the div.

Comment: @DJG Whether it should work or not depends on how you generated it, but I can only tell you it doesn't. Here's one of several starting points for Xpath syntax if you'd like to investigate further. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: @quaabaam yeah, so george's XPath is the correct one since the element name for both sold out and add to cart is the same